# mod-rewritre has no effect:

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my .htaccess file does nothing: any ideas?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.css$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^http://127.0.0.1(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/getcss.php?$1/$2 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*fsite-cookie=([^;]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^http://127.0.0.1(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/cloked.php?$1/$2 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{http_COOKIE} ^.*site-cookie=!([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ htp://127.0.0.1/noaccess.php?$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only rewrite the **path** of the request (unless you send a redirect, but the first part will still have to match the path).

You're trying to match the protocol and host name as well, which will fail.

Try to remove every instance of `http://127.0.0.1` from that configuration.

Comment: tried that now it gives me an error " Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects"

Comment: @tnt: which means you've built up a chain of (probably infinite) redirects. Try to find out why (hint: turn on the rewrite-log).

Comment: Also: your first rule redirects every request *except* `.css` files to `/getcss.php`.

Comment: removing the ! from the css line caused something to happen. but when I http://127.0.0.1/www.test.com the arache error says: File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/www.test.com